# Convert a String to a Map

Tags: java

I have a string with a comma separated values `"name1=John,name2=Jim,name3=Tina"` (this can grow) which i want to convert in a Map with a key value pair as `{name1=John,name2=Jim,name3=Tina}`.

```
String names = "name1=John,name2=Jim,name3=Tina";

Map<String, String> map = Pattern.compile("\\s*-\\s*")
                           .splitAsStream(externalResourcePath.trim())
                           .map(s -> s.split(","))
                           .collect(Collectors.toMap(p -> p[0], p -> p[1]));
```

I am getting output as `{name1=John=name2=Jim}` instead I want the output as `{name1=John,name2=Jim,name3=Tina}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to split by "=" again to separate the key and value.

```
Map<String, String> map = Arrays.stream(names.split(","))
            .map(s -> s.split("="))
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(array -> array[0], array -> array[1]));
```